# a=a++ wondering answer of visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is i=i++ truly a undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968854/is-i-i-truly-a-undefined-behavior)

i just want too explain ++ and -- to my students and show them some code about them in visual studio 2010
I just test this code on it

```
int main(){
   int a=3;
   int b=3;
   a=a++;
   cout<<a<<endl;
   cout<<b++<<endl;
}
```

I expect that both of cout print 3 but the first cout print 4!!!!
I test it in g++ and both of couts print 3...
what's wrong???

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal haha you are so mean :-P

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal you have beaten me to it!

Comment: @Neal: I think Tomalak is setting out to be the unsung hero of many, many future Turbo C++ programmers who don't even know who saved them from certain doom.

Comment: @KerrekSB haha thats what it seems like ^_^

Comment: @KerrekSB: Haha precisely :) [though _sung_ would be preferable]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of `a=a++` is undefined. If you'd like to increment `a`, use `a++` instead.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c

Read about **sequence points**.

Answer (score 1):

`a=a++;` is not well defined. Don't use it.

Comment: It's not even poorly defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed do one assignment within one sequence point in C++ IIRC. So this is undefined. The following presentation discusses this issue in deep http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c .