# code executed with different order between debug and release

Tags: c++, debugging

My environment is vs2013-update-5, I found my code has different result between debug and release, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int increase(int* x) {
    int previous = *x;
    *x += 1;
    return previous;
}
int main() {
    int data = 1;
    int p = 2;

    cout << ((p-data) + increase(&p)) << endl;
}
```

It prints **3** in **debug** mode and **4** in **release** mode. I know there's workaround like:

```
    int x = p-data;
    int y = increase(&p);
    cout << (x + y) << endl;
```

Use some temporary variable to make sure the result. But in my real case, the code is used to parse some buffer to struct, there're lots of length checking like:

```
if((p-data) + 4 + forward<int>(&p) != data_len) return false; 
// forward<unsigned>() increases p with sizeof(int), and return origin p
// just like the previous example
```

So it's best to write with one line code, not using temporary variables.

Why is this happen? Any compile flag causes this? How to make sure the code executed in order?

Comment: It's basically undefined behavior.

Comment: I believe this is straight up undefined behavior. The rules are a bit complicated, but essentially you must not write a variable twice or read and write a variable in the same statement. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968854/is-i-i-truly-a-undefined-behavior#4968880) for some details.