# Comparison inside while loop c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to make when user types number, program should repeat that many times chosing random if
Here is my code

```
cin >> d;
c = 0;

while (c < d) {
    c = c++;
    num = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    if (num == 1) {
        system("start C:\\viewver\\vw");
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
        system("start C:\\viewver\\vw2");
        Sleep(2300);
    }
    else if (num == 3) {
        system("start C:\\viewver\\vw3");
        Sleep(1800);
    }
```

It always chooses to open first one and then stops.

Comment: `num = 1` not the same as `num == 1`

Comment: Typo: `(num = 1)` is always `true`. Crank your compiler warnings up a little. And `c = c++;` is UB currently.

Comment: and this is very odd too `c = c++;`, not even sure if it has well defined behavior

Comment: @Bathsheba - And even if it's not... better treat it like it is UB ;)

Comment: `c = c++` [is unspecified behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968854)

Comment: @DrewDormann: No, in C++14 and earlier it's undefined. This epitomises why you shouldn't trust everything you read on the internet.

Comment: You never seed your random generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` not `=`

```
if (num == 1) {
    system("start C:\\test\\vw");
    Sleep(2000);
}
else if (num == 2) {
    system("start C:\\test\\vw2");
    Sleep(2300);
}
else if (num == 3) {
    system("start C:\\test\\vw3");
    Sleep(1800);
}
```

`==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment

---

The reason why it always chooses the first option is because `C++` (and `C`) has the notion of `truthy` values. So any value that is not `0` is considered truthy, whereas values that evaluate to 0 are considered `falsy`.

In your original code, when you assign `num` to `1`, the value of `num` is truthy, therefore that branch is always taken

Comment: You missed the UB

Comment: it changed so it will always choose last option, but it will open only once and stop.