# What happens during ++iter = iter?

Tags: c++

I had a typo in code recently, that was causing an infinite loop in some cases (but not in all environments, it seems).
It looked like this:

```
for (std::vector<myString>::iterator iter = myVector.begin(); iter != myVector.end(); ++iter = iter)
{
   ...
}
```

The typo is the assignment of the iterator to itself. Removing it fixes the issues.

I am wondering what exactly happens during the statement ++iter = iter?
I thought that according to operator precedence, iterator should first be incremented, then assigned to self, but I seem to be missing some steps (otherwise there would not be infinite loops).
My feeling is that it also involves dereferencing of the variable, but I am not sure to completely understand what was happening with this bug.
Also, why did it seem to not cause infinite loops on some platforms?

Comment: "In C and also in C++, the order of any operation between two [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) is completely up to the compiler and cannot be dependent on." [is i=i++ truly a undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968854/is-i-i-truly-a-undefined-behavior).

Comment: A duplicate question on SO happens.

Comment: @Yonlif c++17 changes the rules rather drastically.

Comment: I didn't know that @n.m. , could you add a link? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171943/487892

Comment: @Yonlif https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17

Comment: I have reopened the question because the proposed dupe is obsolete, due to the new C++17 rules.

Answer (score 3):

> according to operator precedence, iterator should first be incremented, then assigned to self

Operator precedence does not determine evaluation order.

If the expression `d = (a+b)*c`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` can be evaluated in *any* order. `a+b` has to be evaluated after `a` and `b`, `(a+b)*c` after both `a+b` and `c`, and the result of the assignment after both `d` and the result of the multiplication, but that's about it.

The same *used to be the case* with the assignment.

The left-hand side and the right-hand side of the assignment *previously could* be evaluated in any order. In particular, the following order *could* be realised:

- `iter` is evaluated, resulting in a value we call `temp`
- `++iter` is evaluated (this doesn't affect `temp`)

  - this results in incrementing of `iter`, and the value is the newly-incremented `iter` *rvalue*
- `temp` is assigned to the `iter` *rvalue* evaluated above
- the net result is `iter` being unchanged

Another evaluation order also *used to be* possible.

- `++iter` is evaluated

  - this results in incrementing of `iter`, and the value is the newly-incremented `iter` *rvalue*
- `iter` (the right hand side of the assignment) is evaluated again

  - the result is the newly-incremented `iter` converted to *lvalue*
- the assignment takes place, leaving `iter` incremented as expected.

However C++17 [has changed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501587/what-are-the-evaluation-order-guarantees-introduced-by-c17). Assignment is now *evaluated strictly from right to left*. This means the first evaluation order is now *guaranteed*, and the second one is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Maybe adding pseudo-code illustrating the two evaluation orders that used to be possible, would be useful?