# About sequence point and UB

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Here is a question I can not explain clearly.

---

Which option is wrong and why?

```
(A) a += (a++);   
(B) a += (++a);
(C) (a++) += a;
(D) (++a) += (a++);
```

What is the difference between `A` and `B`?

My understand:
`A` is a UB but `B` is OK because the side effect of `++a` will be completed before the assignment. Is that right?

Update: What is the difference between `++a` and `a++` within the sequence point? The side effect of pre-increment(decrement) may be completed any time before the next seq-point just like post-increment(decrement)?

Comment: Multiple choice question!

Comment: @devnull Yes, it is. But I want the clear reason.

Comment: Look at the option `a += (++a);` as this way `a = a + ++a;`

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary in all the statements — but do no harm.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler (Once again, operator precedence is not the same as order of evaluation.)

Comment: @PHI; It is not recommended to see `a += ++a` as `a = a + ++a`.

Comment: @haccks huh? Why, `a += ++a` is recommended or what?

Comment: @H2CO3; I never said `a += ++a` is recommended (it invokes UB). I mean to say `a += b` is not equivalent to `a = a+b`.

Comment: @haccks I asked OP to see this way and find why was it not appropriate  and how does it look to him ? second I didn't want to go that far and include readability issues and all ....... and as far as addition is concerned its perfectly alright to do it like that... its only subtraction where confusion arises .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which option is wrong and why?

All of them are wrong, and that's because the first two invoke undefined behavior, and the last two don't compile. (And if they did, they would invoke UB as well.)

Comment: Why the second one is UB? `a+=(++a)` is equal to `++a; a+=a;`

Comment: @Donglei Oh huh? [Assignment is not a sequence point.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362501/any-good-reason-why-assignment-operator-isnt-a-sequence-point)

Comment: Yes, I know assignment is not a sequence point. Can you explain what is the difference between `++a` and `a++` within the sequence point? My understand: Pre-increment will `++` before return so after `++a` the side-effect has already happend.

Comment: @Donglei And it doesn't matter when the side effects take place, since either way, **`a` is modified twice between sequence points.**

Comment: Yes, exactly. But what about the difference between `++a` and `a++` within the sequence point? I think this is what I confused actually.

Comment: @Donglei Nothing, since the code invokes UB, so there's no point in reasoning about what it does. If you write code that has defined behavior, though, then what you already explained applies (i. e. `a++` yields `a` and `++a` yields `a + 1`).

Comment: @Donglei: pre-increment doesn't work the way you think it does; the expression `++a` will evaluate to the current value of `a` + 1, but the *side effect* of updating `a` doesn't have to happen immediately; in that respect it behaves exactly like the postfix version.

Answer (score 2):

The first and second is UB because C does not define what is supposed to be evaluated first.

The third and fourth do not compile - the reason:  `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Let me be more specific on the first two:

`a += (a++);` - equal to `a = a + (a++);`

- if the `a++` is evaluated first then it's `a = a + 1 + a;`
- if the `a++` is evaluated at the end then it's `a = a + a;`

but C does not define what should happen first, so it depends on the implementation, and it's UB.

The same goes for the second.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can it make demons fly out of your nose? XD

Comment: It depends on the skill of the compiler writer!  I removed my comment; I'm not happy enough with it.  Let's remove these two too.